# SDL2 transparent background

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm trying to create a .PNG image from a larger .PNG image.
Basically clip a rect area of the original and save the result as another .PNG
Sort of like a texture unpacker, if you will.

My issue is that the portions that were transparent in the original image are colored in the clipped image.

Initially I used hardware acceleration and the background was white with speckles, switching to software renderer just changed the background to Black.

I would like to maintain the transparency of the original image.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2_image/SDL_image.h>


void save_texture(const char* file_name, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* texture); // 
save png to disk
SDL_Texture* clipTexture(SDL_Rect rect, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* source); // get 
a new texture that is clipped from the original


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load("LevelItems.png");
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(surface);

    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_Rect frame_rect = { 189, 243,115, 50 };
    SDL_Texture* tex_clip = clipTexture( frame_rect, renderer, texture );

    save_texture("test1.png", renderer, tex_clip);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    return 0;
}

// return a new texture that is a part of the original texture.

SDL_Texture* clipTexture(SDL_Rect rect, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* source)
{
    SDL_Texture* result = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, 
SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, rect.w, rect.h);
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, result);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, source, &rect, NULL);

return result;
}


// save png to disk
void save_texture(const char* file_name, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* texture)
{
    int width, height;
    SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &width, &height);
    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, width, height, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, NULL, surface->format->format, surface->pixels, surface- 
  >pitch);
    IMG_SavePNG(surface, file_name);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}
```

Comment: Before `RenderCopy`, disable blending with `SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(source, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE)`. You may want to restore blending mode afterwards.

Comment: tried it, doesn't work, sorry ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. Disable blending. Use `SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(source, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);` before `RenderCopy`, otherwise you'll get wrong colour (blended with default black - result would be darker than it shound be). Blending tied to texture so if you want to use this texture later you probably should reset blending mode right away. See [SDL_SetTextureBlendMode](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetTextureBlendMode) doc for formulas used in different blend modes.
2. Your resulting surface don't have alpha channel so there is nowhere to copy result. Check documentation for [SDL_CreateRGBSurface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface): while it allows to use `0` for colour masks to deduce default values, it explicitly don't allow it for alpha channel, so `0` in place of `amask` results in "I don't want alpha channel, just RGB". Your resulting format is RGB888 packed to 32bit. You want alpha, so you should use correct colour masks - get one from docs, in your case you don't even need to check for endianess, but it never hurts.

To sum it up:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>


void save_texture(const char* file_name, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* texture);
SDL_Texture* clipTexture(SDL_Rect rect, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* source);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load("test.png");
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(surface);

    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_Rect frame_rect = { 189, 243,115, 50 };
    SDL_Texture* tex_clip = clipTexture( frame_rect, renderer, texture );

    save_texture("test1.png", renderer, tex_clip);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    return 0;
}

// return a new texture that is a part of the original texture.

SDL_Texture* clipTexture(SDL_Rect rect, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* source)
{
    SDL_Texture* result = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, 
SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, rect.w, rect.h);
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, result);
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(source, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, source, &rect, NULL);

return result;
}


// save png to disk
void save_texture(const char* file_name, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* texture)
{
    int width, height;
    SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &width, &height);

    Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
    rmask = 0xff000000;
    gmask = 0x00ff0000;
    bmask = 0x0000ff00;
    amask = 0x000000ff;
#else
    rmask = 0x000000ff;
    gmask = 0x0000ff00;
    bmask = 0x00ff0000;
    amask = 0xff000000;
#endif

    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, width, height, 32, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);

    SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, NULL, surface->format->format, surface->pixels, surface->pitch);
    IMG_SavePNG(surface, file_name);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}
```